# "No such file or directory" error trying to open a RabbitMQ log

Tags: ubuntu, logging, rabbitmq

I'm trying to read a RabbitMQ log file on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. If I run `ls -lhtr`, some files show up:

```
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:/var/log$ ls -lhtr rabbitmq*
total 28K
-rw-r--r-- 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq    0 okt 26 16:40 rabbit@kurt-ThinkPad-sasl.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq  924 okt 26 17:51 rabbit@kurt-ThinkPad.log.6.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq  644 nov 11 11:00 rabbit@kurt-ThinkPad.log.5.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq  646 nov 11 18:47 rabbit@kurt-ThinkPad.log.4.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq  644 nov 22 10:22 rabbit@kurt-ThinkPad.log.3.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq  164 nov 27 07:35 rabbit@kurt-ThinkPad.log.2.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq    0 dec  5 10:12 rabbit@kurt-ThinkPad.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq 4,8K dec  5 10:12 rabbit@kurt-ThinkPad.log.1
```

However, if I try to view the most recent one using `cat`, I get a `No such file or directory` error:

```
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:/var/log$ cat rabbit@kurt-ThinkPad.log.1
cat: rabbit@kurt-ThinkPad.log.1: No such file or directory
```

How can this be?

**Update**

Escaping the `@` with a backslash or enclosing the file name in quotes does not seem to help:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you may need to escape the `@` in the file name, or surround the whole name in quotes

`cat rabbit\@kurt-ThinkPad.log.1`

or

`cat "rabbit@kurt-ThinkPad.log.1"`

Comment: Appreciated, but I still get `No such file or directory` (see screen grab added above).